# Why UICollectionView is not responding at all?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm setting up a `UICollectionView` inside a ViewController. However, it won't respond to any user interaction, `didSelectItemAt` function is not getting called and I am unable to scroll it.

I have set the DataSource and Delegate properly inside the `viewDidLoad()`. Here is my code:

```
class WelcomeController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

let padding: CGFloat = 30
var sources = [Source]()
let sourceCellId = "sourceCellId"

func fetchSources() {
    ApiSourceService.sharedInstance.fetchSources() { (root: Sources) in
        self.sources = root.source
        self.sourceCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

let backgroundImage: UIImageView = {
   let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.image = UIImage(named: "background")
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    iv.clipsToBounds = false
    return iv
}()

let overlayView: UIView = {
   let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    return view
}()

let logo: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.image = UIImage(named: "mylogo")
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    iv.clipsToBounds = false
    return iv
}()

let defaultButton: UIButton = {
    let ub = UIButton()
    ub.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    ub.setTitle("Inloggen met E-mail", for: .normal)
    ub.setImage(UIImage(named: "envelope"), for: .normal)
    ub.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 0, 15, 0)
    ub.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    ub.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
    ub.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.init(name: "Raleway-Regular", size: 16)
    ub.backgroundColor = .cuOrange
    return ub
}()

let continueWithoutButton: UIButton = {
    let ub = UIButton()
    ub.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Doorgaan zonder in te loggen")
    let textRange = NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)
    attributedString.setColor(color: .cuOrange, forText: "Doorgaan")
    ub.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)

    ub.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
    ub.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.init(name: "Raleway-Regular", size: 16)
    ub.titleLabel?.textColor = .white
    return ub
}()


let sourceCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
   let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cv.backgroundColor = .white
    return cv
}()



let termsButton: UIButton = {
    let ub = UIButton()
    ub.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Met het maken van een account \nof bij inloggen, ga ik akkoord \nmet servicevoorwaarden.")
    let textRange = NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)
    attributedString.setColor(color: .cuOrange, forText: "servicevoorwaarden")
    ub.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)

    ub.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
    ub.contentVerticalAlignment = .bottom
    ub.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    ub.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.init(name: "Raleway-Regular", size: 14)
    ub.titleLabel?.textColor = .white
    ub.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    return ub
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchSources()

    sourceCollectionView.dataSource = self
    sourceCollectionView.delegate = self
    sourceCollectionView.register(SourceCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: sourceCellId)

    view.addSubview(backgroundImage)
    view.addSubview(overlayView)
    backgroundImage.addSubview(termsButton)
    backgroundImage.addSubview(logo)
    backgroundImage.addSubview(sourceCollectionView)

    backgroundImage.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 375).isActive = true
    backgroundImage.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 667).isActive = true
    backgroundImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    backgroundImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true



    logo.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundImage.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    logo.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundImage.topAnchor, constant: padding).isActive = true
    logo.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 107).isActive = true
    logo.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

    sourceCollectionView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    sourceCollectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -(padding*1.5)).isActive = true
    sourceCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: logo.bottomAnchor, constant: padding).isActive = true
    sourceCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: termsButton.topAnchor, constant: -(padding*2)).isActive = true

    termsButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -padding).isActive = true
    termsButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    termsButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -(padding*2)).isActive = true
    termsButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

    sourceCollectionView.reloadData()

}

@objc func closeWelcomeController() {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.switchViewControllers()

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {

    })

}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let width = self.sourceCollectionView.frame.width
    let height = CGFloat(50)

    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sources.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    print(sources[indexPath.item].feed_name)

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: sourceCellId, for: indexPath) as! SourceCell
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = true
    cell.source = sources[indexPath.item]

    return cell

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("selecting")
}}
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong here?

I hope there isn't just a "dumb" error inside the code why it's not working, but it's been eating my brain for the past few hours.

Comment: Assign delegate and Datasource to CollectionView in StoryBoard

Comment: This is done inside the viewDidLoad `sourceCollectionView.dataSource = self` and `sourceCollectionView.delegate = self`. I'm not working with StoryBoard

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` should suffice. How did you add the delegate methods? Xcode auto-complete? Or by typing? They need to be the exact function name, or they won't be called.

Comment: Please add them on StoryBoard as well, in storyboard right click on CollectionView and add delegate and datasource

Comment: @LinusGeffarth xCode autocomplete is adding the methods. No errors or warnings.

Comment: @aBilal17 I'm not working with storyboards.

Comment: OP's obviously not working w/ storyboards; nevertheless, that doesn't have anything to do with it. @aBilal17

Comment: OP, are you able to scroll through the collection view in the simulator / on the device?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth it's loading the data, but I indeed can't scroll!

Comment: Then please debug the view hierarchy to see whether the scroll view is on the very top. (when running, in the bottom tool bar of Xcode, the two-rectangles button)

Comment: Your collection view is probably behind something else, maybe your backgroundView. try either calling bringToFront(collectionView) or setting collectionView.layer.zPosition = 10 or some higher number see if that helps

Comment: You've got to be kidding me....how dumb was I. I added the subView of the collectionview to the background view...instead of the view it self. I guess I need sleep now! Thanks for helping guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is *inappropriate* to add `sourceCollectionView` as a subview in `backgroundImage` which is `UIImageView`! Logically, image view doesn't represent a container view (such as `UIView` `UIStackView`, `UIScrollView`) i.e even if the code lets you do that, it still non-sensible; Furthermore, even if adding a subview to an image view is ok (which is *not*), image views by default are user interaction disabled ([`userInteractionEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622577-userinteractionenabled) is `false` by default for image views), that's why you are unable to even scroll the collection view, it is a part (subview) of a disabled user interaction component.

In your `viewDidLoad()`, you are implementing:

```
backgroundImage.addSubview(termsButton)
backgroundImage.addSubview(logo)
backgroundImage.addSubview(sourceCollectionView)
```

Don't do this, instead, add them to main view of the view controller:

```
view.addSubview(termsButton)
view.addSubview(logo)
view.addSubview(sourceCollectionView)
```

*For the purpose of checking if its the reason of the issue, at least do it for the collection view (`view.addSubview(sourceCollectionView)`).*

And for the purpose of organizing the hierarchy of the view (which on is on top of the other), you could use both: [`bringSubview(toFront:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622541-bringsubview) or [`sendSubview(toBack:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622618-sendsubview). For instance, after adding the collection view into the `view`, you might need to:

```
view.bringSubview(toFront: sourceCollectionView)
```

to make sure that the collection view is on top of all components.

Answer (score 0):

I see you add sourceCollectionView to subview of backgroundImage. Your backgroundImage is UIImageView so UIImageView doesn't have user interaction except you need to enable it. The problem of your code is

```
backgroundImage.addSubview(sourceCollectionView)
```

For my suggestion you should create UIView or other views that can interact with user interaction. It will work fine.